# Syntax for find on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, unix, find, syntax

I have a project directory that contains source code and subdirectories of source code.  I want to use the Unix program `find` to search recursively for the names of files of certain extensions.  The versions of `find` on Linux and Mac OS X behave differently.

```
# Works in Linux
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(py\|html\)$"

# Neither of these works in Mac OS X
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(py\|html\)$"
find . -type f -regex ".*\.(py|html)$"
```

How do I write this command so that it will run on Mac OS X (and hopefully on Linux too)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us in what way they behave differently.

Comment: The command is supposed to find files.  On OS X, the same command finds nothing (zero files).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mac OS X uses BSD [find](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and most Linux distributions come with GNU [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).  I believe you can install GNU findutils onto Mac OS X.  I don't have a Mac handy, but I am sure it was available in [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts).

Looking at the BSD find man page I could make a wild guess and suggest you try looking at the `-E` option to enable the modern regular expression library.

Comment: Getting findutils from MacPorts did the trick.

Comment: Findutils is also available through Homebrew.  The command after installing is `gfind`

Answer (score 4):

The following work with BSD find on OS X.

```
find -E . -type f -regex ".*\.(py|html)$"

find . -type f | grep -e ".*\.\(py\|html\)$"
```